# Theorem environment and Fancybox

Tags: environments, boxes, fancybox

I would like to define my own theorem and to capture it around a double (or oval) box as it specified in `fancybox` package. Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\useackage{amsmath,fancybox}

\newtheorem{test}{Test}

\begin{document}

\doublebox{%
\begin{test}
bla bla bla
\end{test}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you should have a look at `tcolorbox`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `tcolorbox`, which allows for much power over customizations than `fancybox`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem{test}{Test}
\tcolorboxenvironment{test}{
  enhanced,
  borderline={0.8pt}{0pt}{black},
  borderline={0.4pt}{2pt}{black},
  boxrule=0.4pt,
  colback=white,
  coltitle=black,
  sharp corners,
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{test}
bla bla bla
\end{test}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution with the`framed` option from `ntheorem` and the eponymous package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,fancybox}

\usepackage{framed}

 \usepackage[thmmarks, thref, amsmath, framed]{ntheorem}

  \def\theoremframecommand{\doublebox}
  \theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}
  \theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
  \theoremseparator{.}
  \newshadedtheorem{thmtest}{Test}

\begin{document}

\begin{thmtest}
Bla bla bla
\end{thmtest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @gigabytes: I hate repeating myself… ;o)

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,fancybox}
\usepackage{calc}
\newtheorem{test}{Test}

\newenvironment{boxedtest}
{\noindent\begin{Sbox}\begin{minipage}{\linewidth-7.5\fboxrule-2\fboxsep-1pt}\begin{test}}
{\end{test}\end{minipage}\end{Sbox}\doublebox{\TheSbox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{boxedtest}
  bla bla bla
\end{boxedtest}

\end{document}
```

[image]